# Make google script update html

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to make a Google Script that reads a Spreadsheet and them send that information to a simple HTML, but I do not know how send information collected  on Google scrip to java script.

Here is the code:

**Google Script**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

    function getUserName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1MRr0iZJoK-mfzIM6nMgycAg8BpPOCt3X-ndwYPZ3BeA").getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, lastRow);
  var Names = range.getValues();
  return Names;
}
```

**HTML and JavaScript**

```
<script>
  function createPost() {
    var name[] = google.script.run.getUserName();
    var Post_area = document.getElementById('post_area');
    for(var i=0; i < qnt; i++){
      var element = document.createElement("div");
      element = div.innerHTML ='<img src="' + img[i] + '" alt="' + name[i] + '" id="image"><p"' + name[i] + '"></p>';
      Post_area.appendChild(element);
    }
    return 0;
  }
</script>

<section>
  <article id="post_area">
  </article>
</section>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a little [demo](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxl5hSxKE4Pp8jFLRcH8hmOJnqamxRl8qng7hFKvv3kSmXfo9ku/exec) and the [code](https://script.google.com/a/macros/ousset.net/d/1vVe1iG_YXN22JRWnu3g181cqPG8JdPCGSTyEvz6goDfZbxBtNbmgEg1k/edit?template=default&folder=0B402g19G1-G-a3J4QUhFNlFpX2s&usp=drive_web).

the code is yours, with little modifications:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function getUserName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Ao02g19G1-G-dDF1M3MyMDJWODlFMkV4N1hDWThWZEE").getSheetByName("peoples")
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 2);
  var Names = range.getValues();
  return Names;
}
```

and the index.html page:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPost).getUserName();
  });

  function createPost(name) {
    name = name || google.script.run.getUserName();
    var Post_area = document.getElementById('post_area');
    Post_area.innerHTML="";
    for(var i in name){
      var element = document.createElement("div");
      element.innerHTML ='<img src="' + name[i][0] + '" alt="' + name[i][1] + '" id="image"><p>&nbsp;' + name[i][1] + '</p>';
      Post_area.appendChild(element);
    }
    return 0;
  }
</script>

<section>
  <div> <h3>Starwar peoples</h3></div>
  <article id="post_area">Loading....
  </article>
  <div> spreadsheet ref <a href="https://docs.google.com/a/ousset.net/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao02g19G1-G-dDF1M3MyMDJWODlFMkV4N1hDWThWZEE&usp=drive_web#gid=1">here</a></div>
</section>
```

What I changed:

in the index.html page I added   `window.addEventListener('load',function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPost).getUserName();});` so it can load the code in the script and in the page.

Then in your code I changed the way you where calling the spreadsheet data, because you are calling only one column (and I needed two column of data to display name and url.
In the JS code of the page, you were making reference to `img[i]` that was never declared. 
I also changed  `element = div.innerHTML` for `element.innerHTML` and I changed the for loop (because I prefer to do it my way and because you made a loop on a undeclared variable).
Well I think that's all.
Good luck for the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much, its working very fine!!! I just want to undestend better what that part of the code does: 'window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPost).getUserName();'
  });

Comment: "window.addEventListener('load'" wait for the page to load the html and then execute the code in "function()". the function: "google.script.run"..."getUserName()" run the server function "getUserName()" then give the return of that function to the function "createPost(return)" that is executed on the client side. Yep I must admit it's a bit compressed/complex you'll found everything about that here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication?hl=fr